# Generic class constructor failing with a class cast exception error at runtime

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to make my own generic linkedlist data type but am having trouble with the constructor and am getting a class cast exception. Anyone know how to fix this and WHY this is happening?

**Here is my relevant code:**

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<E> {

   private LinkedListNode<E>[] linkedListNodeList;

   public SinglyLinkedList()
   {
       linkedListNodeList = (SinglyLinkedListNode<E>[]) new Object[10];
   }

}
```

The offending line is the implementation line in the constructor.

Here is my SinglyLinkedListNode class:

```
public class SinglyLinkedListNode<E> extends LinkedListNode<E>{

   private E data;

   public SinglyLinkedListNode(E data)
   {
       this.data = data;
   }
}
```

And my LinkedListNode class is simply an empty (for now) abstract class that SinglyLinkedListNode extends.

**Here is the compiler error I'm receiving:**

java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LabstractDataTypes.SinglyLinkedListNode;
    at abstractDataTypes.SinglyLinkedList.(SinglyLinkedList.java:23)

Comment: The type of `new Object[10]` is `Object[]`. It's not `SinglyLinkedListNode<E>[]`. Casting an object to a type doesn't change the type of the object. You can't cast a Car to a Bird and hope that the car will transform itself to a bird. You can cast an Animal to a Bird if the animal actually is a bird. That said, why would you need an array of nodes in a linked list? Have you understood what a linked list is?

Answer (score 2):

An `Object[]` is not compatible with any other array (e.g. `String[]`). But this will work:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<E> {

   private LinkedListNode<E>[] linkedListNodeList;

   public SinglyLinkedList()
   {
       linkedListNodeList = (SinglyLinkedListNode<E>[]) new SinglyLinkedListNode<?>[10];
   }
}
```

Note that it is also not possible to use `new SinglyLinkedListNode<E>[10]`, as generic arrays can't be created in general:

```
E[] myArray = new E[10]; // doesn't work, if E is a generic type parameter
```